# Usage of "Before"

Tags: usage, prepositional-phrases, ellipsis

I have some question about the usage of "before" [here](http://sbohp.com/southbaydoctor6.html):

> Dr. Tom Chen lives in Palo Alto with his wife Aline, daughter, Laura, and son, Jason. ***Before the demands of parenthood and clinical practice***, Dr. Chen enjoyed playing the violin with a chamber music group and participating in triathlons.

Is something missing between "*before*" and "*the demands of...*"?  Would a rewrite like this:

> Dr. Tom Chen lives in Palo Alto with his wife Aline, daughter, Laura, and son, Jason. Before ***handling*** the demands of parenthood and clinical practice, Dr. Chen enjoyed playing the violin with a chamber music group and participating in triathlons.

be better?

Comment: simply 'before x happened' It needs nothing else. Before I ate lunch, I washed my hands… although I suppose it has an unstated 'before xxx [took all his time up]'

Comment: And the xxx that happened need not have a verb: _Before the World's Fair, Chicago had no Ferris Wheel._  It is just an inversion of _Chicago had no Ferris Wheel before the World's Fair._

Comment: @Tetsujin Would "*before* ***taking on*** *the demands of* ..." be better?

Comment: @Adam Would "*before* ***taking on*** *the demands of* ..." be better?

Comment: It would be different.  Better?  Depends if you want to emphasize that he took on demands, or you want to emphasize what he did before.  Really not very different, though.

Answer (score 1):

"Before the demands" - Dr. Chen enjoyed playing the violin is the activity that Dr. Chen enjoyed BEFORE parenthood and clinical practice took priority.

"before the handling of demands" is not incorrect, but it is like saying, "After the issue with my boss, I quit". You could say "After dealing with the issue with my boss, I quit" but it is generally understood both Dr. Chen and you "dealt with" or handled the situation.

Comment: Would "*before* ***taking on*** *the demands of* ..." be better?

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, I find the phrase without an -ing verb before it to be less readable.

So, to me, it would be 'better' as far as readability (not grammar) to have something such as *Before having/tackling/experiencing/taking on the demands of...*

Either that, or include a verb at the end of the first part: *Before the demands of parenthood and clinical practice arose/came along,...*

Again I'm speaking in terms of what reads easier to me, that is: what constructions I expect to see in a certain context.